# RSpec passing object as a param in a controller_spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I have a users_controller_spec.rb with this:

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it "assigns a newly created user as @user" do
      post :create, user: user
      assigns(:user).should be_a(User)
      assigns(:user).should be_persisted
    end
  end

 ...

end
```

Debuggin I found that the controller receive the next params

```
(rdb:1) pp params
{"user"=>"1", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create"}
```

Why "user" => "1" ?, why is not passing the user object properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`post :create` expects attributes for the user model that it will use to create a user record.  you are seeing "user" => "1" because it is passing in the id of the user you created into the :user parameter.

You dont want to create a user record to test the create action.  You want to create a hash of attributes for the create action to create the record.

You could write something like this (assuming this would pass your model validations):

```
user_attributes = { :email => "something@example.com", :username => "something" }
post :create, user: user_attributes
```